# How to override existing field in Siteorigin?

Tags: wordpress, siteorigin

I want to make a custom field for the existing field type `color`, the default from Siteorigin widget bundle. Basically, what I need to create my own UI and backend logic for the `color` field type.

As this field is used in many places, if I could override the field type directly, will automatically work in every place.

I searched many times, and also dig through the source code of widgets bundle and SO itself, but couldn't find what I needed, even I tried to load my fields folder with `0` priority (highest) but didn't work. Its still displaying the default color field type.

Can anybody point me to some actions or filters, so that, I can de-register and re-register with the same type `color`? Or if any other workaround possible?

---

### UPDATE

My question focus is for **Siteorigin Widgets Bundle Plugin**.

I don't want to just override any style variables, rather want to override existing fields. After some research, I found 2 filters that could be used to override existing field(s):

```
// Give other plugins a way to modify this form.
$form_options = apply_filters( 'siteorigin_widgets_form_options', $form_options, $this );
$form_options = apply_filters( 'siteorigin_widgets_form_options_' . $this->id_base, $form_options, $this );
```

The two filters get called in method `form_options()` in class `SiteOrigin_Widget` but this method is called like this:

```
public function form( $instance, $form_type = 'widget' ) {

    if( $form_type == 'widget' ) {
        if( empty( $this->form_options ) ) {
            $this->form_options = $this->form_options();
        }
        $form_options = $this->form_options;
    }

...
...

}
```

But it looks like `$this->form_options` is never empty and so, method `$this->form_options()` is never called which in turn never applies the filters `siteorigin_widgets_form_options` and `siteorigin_widgets_form_options_<id_base>`

And thus, my chance of modifying the form fields becomes `zero` with this approach.

What I basically need is for eg. there is an existing field `color` and I have another custom field `adv-color`. Now, the challenge is to override all instance of `color` field to `adv-color` and thus every instance of the field is overridden. But, it's still a hope.

Please let me know if my approach is wrong or is there is another way to solve this. Example(s) is/are greatly expected.

Comment: SiteOrigin is a _company_, so it's hard to be sure which plugin / widget specifically you are referring to.  Can you please provide a link to the specific plugin?  And - if it is the "Widgets Bundle" (which you say), which widget specifically is it that you are asking about?

Comment: @cale_b Sorry for the confusion, I meant Siteorigin Widgets Bundle Plugin.

Comment: Why do you want to override the existing _field_? My solution to the first version of this question overrides the _color generated_.  What difference does it make to override the color field in the widget controls, vs. overriding the color _value_ that is output when the widget is rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anybody point me to some actions or filters, so that, I can
>   de-register and re-register with the same type `color`? Or if any other
>   workaround possible?

I don't see a way to de-register and re-register the `color` field *type* (or generator).

However, if you want to customize the field's *UI* (or even completely change its look n' feel), you can create a PHP `class` which extends one of these `class`es: `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Base`, `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Text_Input_Base`, or `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color`. See a simple example below:

```
// File: class-my-siteorigin-widget-field-color.php
class My_SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color extends SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color {

    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        // Enqueues custom CSS and/or JS files, if any.

        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'path/to/file.js', [ 'jquery' ], '20180601' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-stylesheet', 'path/to/file.css', [], '20180601' );
    }

    // Here you can modify the field's UI to your liking. Even a totally new UI.
    protected function render_field( $value, $instance ) {
        ?>
        <b>Text before</b>
        <input type="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->input_type ) ?>"
               name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->element_name ) ?>"
               id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->element_id ) ?>"
                 value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ) ?>"
                 <?php $this->render_data_attributes( $this->get_input_data_attributes() ) ?>
                 <?php $this->render_CSS_classes( $this->get_input_classes() ) ?>
            <?php if ( ! empty( $this->placeholder ) ) echo 'placeholder="' . esc_attr( $this->placeholder ) . '"' ?>
            <?php if( ! empty( $this->readonly ) ) echo 'readonly' ?> />
        <i>Text after</i>
        <?php
    }

    // See `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Base` for all the properties and methods you
    // can extend. See also `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Text_Input_Base`, which is
    // being extended by `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color`.
}
```

You should then load the `class` in/during the `init` hook in WordPress. **Example:**

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/class-my-siteorigin-widget-field-color.php';
} );
```

And then, to force `color` fields to use the custom `class` (above), add the `class` name *prefix* to the `$prefixes` `array` below:

```
add_filter( 'siteorigin_widgets_field_class_prefixes', function( $prefixes ){
    return array_merge( [ 'My_SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_' ], $prefixes );
} );
```

Unfortunately, you can't `unset` or remove `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color` from the `class` list, because the above filter only allows you to filter the `class` name *prefixes*.

But in the example callback above, the custom `My_SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color` would be "seen" first by the SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle plugin; hence, `color` fields would use the custom `class` in place of the default one — i.e. `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color`.

For more details on that, see [`SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Factory::get_class_prefixes()`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/so-widgets-bundle/tags/1.11.8/base/inc/fields/factory.class.php) and the entire `SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Factory` source code. And [`SiteOrigin_Widget::form()`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/so-widgets-bundle/tags/1.11.8/base/siteorigin-widget.class.php#L457).

See also:

- [`SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Base`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/so-widgets-bundle/tags/1.11.8/base/inc/fields/base.class.php)
- [`SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Text_Input_Base`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/so-widgets-bundle/tags/1.11.8/base/inc/fields/text-input-base.class.php)
- [`SiteOrigin_Widget_Field_Color`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/so-widgets-bundle/tags/1.11.8/base/inc/fields/color.class.php)

**UPDATE**

> But it looks like `$this->form_options` is never empty and so, method
>   `$this->form_options()` is never called which in turn never applies the
>   filters `siteorigin_widgets_form_options` and
>   `siteorigin_widgets_form_options_<id_base>`
>
> And thus, my chance of modifying the form fields becomes `zero` with
>   this approach.

The following example may help you: (or rather, it worked well for me)

```
// Extends the fields for the Button widget.
// @see SiteOrigin_Widget_Button_Widget::get_widget_form()
// @see SiteOrigin_Widget::form_options()
add_filter( 'siteorigin_widgets_form_options_sow-button', function( $form_options, $widget ){
    if ( isset( $form_options['button_icon'] ) ) {
        // `icon_color` is an existing/built-in field for the Button widget. So
        // in this example, we change the `label` from 'Icon color' to 'Icon
        // default color'.
        $form_options['button_icon']['fields']['icon_color']['label'] = 'Icon default color';

        // Or you could completely override the field:
        /*
        $form_options['button_icon']['fields']['icon_color'] = [
            'type'  => 'custom_type_here',
            'label' => 'Icon color',
        ];
        */

        // And here, we add a new field: A color for the button's `hover` state.
        $form_options['button_icon']['fields']['icon_hover_color'] = [
            'type'  => 'color',
            'label' => 'Icon hover color',
        ];
    }

    return $form_options;
}, 10, 2 );

// Callback to handle the `icon_hover_color`.
add_action( 'siteorigin_widgets_after_widget_sow-button', function( $instance, $widget ){
    if ( isset( $instance['button_icon'], $instance['button_icon']['icon_hover_color'] ) ) {
        $selector = $widget->is_preview( $instance ) ?
            '.so-widget-sow-button' : '#' . $widget->id;
        ?>
            <style>
                <?= $selector ?> a:hover .sow-icon-fontawesome {
                    color: <?= $instance['button_icon']['icon_hover_color'] ?> !important;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

However, even if you set the `color` fields to other `type` (e.g. `adv_color`), you'd still need to create the appropriate PHP `class` and then add the `class` name *prefix* via the `siteorigin_widgets_field_class_prefixes` hook.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. Let me try this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Looks like that it a good workaround. Now I wonder, why even the developers of Siteorigin Widgets Bundle ever made these filters `'siteorigin_widgets_form_options'` & `'siteorigin_widgets_form_options_' . $this->id_base`. And even they commented above it: "Give other plugins a way to modify this form.". And literally, they don't work. This is ridiculous. Anyway, your answer truly helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the filter does work. See the example in the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

*(NOTE: This answer is for the [question as originally asked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50477245/1).  The question was modified after this answer was posted, so the answer below may not seem like the correct answer to the question in it's current state.)*

[SiteOrigin Widget Bundle](https://siteorigin.com/widgets-bundle/) comes with a wide variety of widgets.

Each widget compiles it's own css, utilizing [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) variables.

As you can change the color(s) explicitly for each widget, these variables are stored in the database and retrieved individually for each individual widget and then compiled into widget-specific CSS files.  This happens on "Save" of the widget, and the CSS is cached for 7 days.

In order to override the variables for these widgets, you have a few different filters to choose from (refer to the `siteorigin-widget.class.php` plugin file, the `get_instance_css` method, starting around line 816 to see the code that does this).  FYI you'll want to do it that this level, since this is a "base" class to all of the individual widgets.

**Filter 1:**

```
$vars = apply_filters( 'siteorigin_widgets_less_variables_' . $this->id_base, $this->get_less_variables( $instance ), $instance, $this );
```

This would be an ideal place, because `$vars` is an array of all the defined colors, and you could easily override any of them that you like.  **However**, the problem is that this filter would be difficult to leverage, since it bakes in the `id_base` of the widget, which results in filter tags like `siteorigin_widgets_less_variables_sow-accordion` - however, you could in theory set up a long list of filters, one for each widget, that all run through the same function.

**Filter 2:**
There's a filter shortly after that one, however the LESS variables have already been "written" into the LESS:

```
$less = apply_filters( 'siteorigin_widgets_styles', $less, $this->widget_class, $instance );
```

This is the filter that needs to be used, but you'll need to know the LESS variable names you want to replace.  That list (at least some of them) is:

```
$vars = ‌array (
  'heading_background_color'       => '',
  'heading_background_hover_color' => '',
  'title_color'                    => '',
  'title_hover_color'              => '',
  'heading_border_color'           => '',
  'heading_border_hover_color'     => '',
  'heading_border_width'           => '',
  'has_heading_border_width'       => '',
  'panels_background_color'        => '',
  'panels_font_color'              => '',
  'panels_border_color'            => '',
  'panels_border_width'            => '',
  'has_panels_border_width'        => '',
  'panels_margin_bottom'           => '',
}
```

**Building a Solution:**
Armed with this information, we can apply filters like so:

```
function my_siteorigin_override_less( $less ) {
    // you'll need to load your override colors here.  that is outside the scope of this question / answer
    $my_colors = array(
      'heading_background_color'       => '#fff',
      'heading_background_hover_color' => '#ff0',
      'title_color'                    => '#000'
      // any other colors you want to include / override....
    );

    foreach( $my_colors as $name => $value ) {
        // Ignore empty string, false and null values (but keep '0')
        if( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $less = preg_replace('/\@'.preg_quote($name).' *\:.*?;/', '@'.$name.': '.$value.';', $less);
        }
    }

    return $less;
}

add_filter( 'siteorigin_widgets_styles', 'my_siteorigin_override_less' );
```

The above code is tested, and proven to work.

**Notes:**
SiteOrigin "caches" the CSS it builds for 7 days.  That means that if you have widgets already set up, and you change the default color, the changes will not be reflected until the cache is purged somehow.

There is a utility method in the SiteOrigin code that you can use to "purge" the cache when you need to.  I would recommend that you do something like below *any time* the "default" colors are saved / updated:

```
if ( is_callable( 'SiteOrigin_Widget', 'clear_file_cache' ) ) {
    // pass TRUE to force delete
    SiteOrigin_Widget::clear_file_cache( TRUE );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the question might be confusing for you, actually my question is for overriding existing field by my custom field, not just the styles and its variables. I've updated the question for better understanding. Hope this may clarify my question better.

Comment: I put a _ton_ of work into this answer, which completely and accurately answers [your question as asked when I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50477245/1).  Your edits _completely_ change the nature of the question.

Comment: Yeah, I've got to agree here. I think @SukantaPaul needs to re-read [ask]. Asking bad questions doesn't just make you less likely to get an answer, it wastes other peoples time.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry if my question caused misunderstanding. I thought "create my own UI and backend logic for the color field type" and "actions or filters, so that, I can de-register and re-register with the same type color" clearly asks I want to override the field type with my own field type altogether.

Comment: @ThallerThanYall Does that mean I won't get any more help from anyone? But I tried to specify I want to override "field type" please check my last comment.

Comment: The change you made to your question changes the scope dramatically, and I don't have time to do it all over _again_ on this.  This is the sort of thing that nobody knows off the top of their head, but rather has to research, put time into developing an answer, etc - which I did once already.  Plus, honestly, now I don't trust that the answer won't change _again_ once I put more time in.  So sorry, this is as much as I'm going to do.